# transfer files using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have to transfer files from my remote computer to amazon ec2 and then from there to Amazon s3 using python . I have successfully uploaded one text file but dont know how to upload multiple files. Here are the codes for two programs for one file.

to get file to ec2

```
import urllib
source = urllib.urlopen('url').read()
fhand = open('file2.txt','w')
fhand.write(source)
fhand.close()
```

to upload file to s3

```
import boto
from boto.s3.key import Key
keyId = "acess key"
skeyId = "secret key"

fileName="file2.txt"
bucketName="bname"
file=open(fileName)

conn = boto.connect_s3(keyId,skeyId)
print conn
bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucketName)
print bucket
k = Key(bucket)
print k
k.key=fileName
print k.key
result = k.set_contents_from_file(file)
print result
```

Comment: Iterate over the same code using the `for` loop. What is the issue?

Comment: not getting exact iteration idea, i am a fresher its been 2 months i started working @MoinuddinQuadri

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Looping to get files from ec2

```
import urllib,os
sources = ['//url1/file1.txt','//url2/file2.txt','//url3/file3.txt'] # List of urls
for myurl in sources:
    source = urllib.urlopen(myurl).read() #Open each url file
    fname = os.path.split(myurl)[1]       #Split the url to get the file name 
    print('Copying file:',fname)
    fhand = open(fname,'w')
    fhand.write(source)
    fhand.close()
```

Use the same principle to send files from a `list` mylist=["a","b","c"]
https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Notes:
If the same file name is used in different urls, the results will be overwritten, so you will want to add a test or some other coping mechanism, if that is a probability.
I have used `os.path.split()` to get the file name, you may find that the `urlparse` function gives you better mileage, with more complicated urls

Comment: My mistake, edited to loop over list of urls, not file names

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can transfer files with [pyformulas](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyformulas), if python is installed on each machine.

First install pyformulas `pip install pyformulas==0.2.7`

Then run the server (receives the files):

Server:

```
import pyformulas as pf

class server(pf.net.Stream):
    file = bytes()
    def on_receive(self, conn, buffer):
        self.file += buffer

    def on_disconnect(self, conn):
        with open('file_%i' % self.port, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(self.file)

servers = [server(port=1000+i) for i in range(3)]
```

Then the client (sends the files):

Client:

```
import pyformulas as pf

class send_file(pf.net.Stream):
    def __init__(self, port, file, address):
        self.file = file
        super(send_file, self).__init__(port, address)

    def on_connect(self, conn):
        conn.send(self.file)
        conn.disconnect()

filenames = ['0.txt', '1.wav', '2.bin'] # Put the filenames here

[ send_file(port=1000+idx, file=open(fname, 'rb').read(), address='server ip address') for idx, fname in enumerate(filenames) ]
```